# Manage when someone tries to close the browser window/tab

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, onbeforeunload

In my onbeforeunload event, it asked the user whether they want to leave the page or stay on it. When they click "stay on page", I want it to then redirect them to another webpage in the same window. It sounds weird, but that's what I've been assigned to do. Basically, the main page plays a video - I think advertising to buy something, and when they close but then decide to stay on the page, we want the video to go away/stop playing and some different information to appear (a different "webpage"). Is there a way to do this, without just showing/hiding divs? Can I override the function? I'm currently trying to do it this way(as seen below) but now the dialog box is not showing up at all. It was working before  Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong, or how to accomplish this task?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>The Shocking Truth - Cabot Market Letter</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#vid").show();
            $("#div2").hide();
        });
        var test = 1;
        function manipulatetest()
        {
            test = 2;
        }
    window.onbeforeunload = onbeforeunload_Handler;
    function onbeforeunload_Handler()
    {       if (test == 1){

                $("#vid").hide();
                $("#div2").show();
            var confirm = confirm("Would you like to stay on this page?");
            if (confirm == true) {
                window.location = "http://www.google.com";
                }

        }
}

</script>
</head>

<style type="text/css"> 

body {
    background-color: #e0e6e5;
}

#vid {  
    margin: 20px auto;
    width: 920px;
}

</style>


<body>

<div id="vid">
    <video width="920" height="540" autoplay preload controls>
      <source src="shockingtruth.mp4"  type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
      <source src="shockingtruth.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"'>
      <source src="shockingtruth.ogv"  type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>
      <object width="920" height="540" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
        data="flowplayer-3.2.1.swf"> 
        <param name="movie" value="flowplayer-3.2.7.swf" /> 
        <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" /> 
        <param name="flashvars" value='config={"clip": {"url": "http://www.cabot.net/videos/shocking-truth/shockingtruth.mp4", "autoPlay":true, "autoBuffering":true}}' /> 
        <p>Download video as <a href="pr6.mp4">MP4</a>, <a href="pr6.webm">WebM</a>, or <a href="pr6.ogv">Ogg</a>.</p> 
      </object>
    </video>
</div>

<div id="div2">
    <video width="920" height="540" autoplay preload controls>
      <source src="shockingtruth.mp4"  type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
      <source src="shockingtruth.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"'>
      <source src="shockingtruth.ogv"  type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>
      <object width="920" height="540" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
        data="flowplayer-3.2.1.swf"> 
        <param name="movie" value="flowplayer-3.2.7.swf" /> 
        <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" /> 
        <param name="flashvars" value='config={"clip": {"url": "http://www.cabot.net/videos/shocking-truth/shockingtruth.mp4", "autoPlay":true, "autoBuffering":true}}' /> 
        <p>Download video as <a href="pr6.mp4">MP4</a>, <a href="pr6.webm">WebM</a>, or <a href="pr6.ogv">Ogg</a>.</p> 
      </object>
    </video>
</div>

<p style="text-align: center;"><a href="http://www.cabot.net/info/cml/cmlld03.aspx?source=ed01" onclick="manipulatetest();">Click Here To Order</a></p>

</body>
```

Comment: it really sounds like the most annoying user experience ever.

Comment: jQuery was not designed for evil. =P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dirty trick is a `setTimeout`, and see whether it still runs: http://jsfiddle.net/FJ4LR/1/.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        alert('You clicked stay.');
    }, 500);

    return 'Really?';
};
```

Comment: Okay, this works nicely - how would I handle it to do something when they decide to stay on the page?

Comment: @OhMisterRabbit: Instead of that alert just code something else that should happen instead. Like replacing it with `window.location = "http://www.google.com";`.

Comment: @OhMisterRabbit: Yes, that's exactly what I was trying to say. Could you try that?

Comment: I tried it, but it just closed the page. My boss got something working though - I'm not entirely sure how he did it :/ But this example will be good for future reference. Thanks!